# C: Recursive function for inverting an int

Tags: c, recursion, integer

I had this problem on an exam yesterday. I couldn't resolve it so you can imagine the result...

Make a recursive function: **int invertint( int num)** that will receive an integer and return it but inverted, example: **321** would return as **123**

I wrote this:

```
int invertint( int num ) {
  int rest = num % 10;
  int div = num / 10;
  if( div == 0 ) {
     return( rest );
  }
  return( rest * 10 + invert( div ) )
}
```

Worked for 2 digits numbers but not for 3 digits or more. Since **321** would return **1 * 10 + 23** in the last stage.

Thanks a lot!

PS: Is there a way to understand these kind of recursion problems in a faster manner or it's up to imagination of one self?

Comment: Have you considered convert it to char* and call a recursive function with a char*? It makes things easier probably, but I don't know if you were allowed to do this

Comment: What shall the result of `1230` be, `3210` or `321`?

Comment: @JoSo I think there can't be a leading 0 in a integer... so I guess it would be: 1230: 321

Comment: If you are looking at hints on how to solve this kind of problem, my suggestions would be 1) Try to stick to a `if(is_base_case){ basecase } else { recursive_case }` structure. It gets natural with practice and 2) Learn how to convert tail recursion to while loops and vice versa. Many kinds of problems fall under this category

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int invertint( int num ) {
  int i ;

  for(i=10;num/i;i*=10);
  i/=10;
  if(i == 1) return num;
  return( (num % 10) * i + invertint( num / 10 ) );
}
```

Comment: Works perfect, thank you.

If it's not disturbing, could you explain how you thought it?

Thanks!

Comment: @Jorge: The idea is to recurse the other way around -- instead of handling the rightmost digit first, you handle the leftmost. That's what the loop does here and the `log10`/`pow` combination does in my answer. The rest comes rather naturally.

Comment: @Jorge - i:10^floor(log10(num)), cha0site explained.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is that in the last statement you are multiplying `rest` by `10`. Why only `10`? You need to shift the `rest` digit by as many digits as there are left in the remaining part of the number. You are shifting by only 1. No wonder it works only for 2-digit numbers.

The last part should be done along the lines of

```
int tail = invert( div );
int deg = /* number of digits in `tail` */;
return rest * (int) pow(10, deg) + div;
```

Comment: +1. This was the answer, I also thought of. But, shouldn't it be (number of digits in tail - 1). For Ex: 321 has 3 digits, so it should be rest * pow(10, 2) when it executes for the last time.

Comment: @Jay: `tail` in this case is actually the *remaining* portion of the number (which has already been fed through the recursive call). I.e. if the original number was `321`, then `rest` is `1`, while `tail` is `23`. So, `deg` will be `2`, exactly as it should be. However, I already see a problem with this solution if `tail` ends up with leading zeros after inversion. The number of digits should be calculated *before* the recursive call. BLUEPIXY does it correctly in the accepted solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
int reverse(int no,int rev)
{
if(no!=0)
return reverse(no/10,rev*10+no%10);
else
return rev;
}
```

call this method as **reverse(numberToReverse,0)**

Comment: Your 2nd function doesn't really work, you aren't even using the result of the recursive call.

Comment: No, it won't work. You aren't even returning a value from the function. -1 for arguing when you obviously didn't test it.

Comment: @interjay I have removed that function. After I tested it, I will post it.

Comment: OK, -1 removed. I don't think there is a simple way to answer the question without adding an extra parameter or counting the number of digits.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an alternative, this could be done without recursion.

```
    int invertint(int num)
    {
        int res = 0;
        while (num != 0)
        {                
            res = res * 10 + (num % 10);
            num /= 10;
        }
        return res;
    }
```

But since recursion was the assignment, given the int(int) signature, easiest would be with a pow(log10)) variation (provided that you're allowed to include math.h ? )

```
    int invertint(int num)
    {
        if (num == 0) return 0;
        return invertint(num / 10)  +  (int)pow(10, (int)log10(num)) * (num % 10);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do it the other way, you won't need a counter.

```
int invertint(int num)
{
    if (0 == num || 0 == num % 10) {
        return num / 10;
    }
    int digits = floor(log10(num)) + 1;
    int modulus = pow(10, digits - 1);
    return invertint(num % modulus) * 10 + num / modulus;
}
```

Note that this isn't as simple as I originally thought - I had to use math.

Comment: This is the same as Rafael Baptista's answer, and is just as wrong.

Comment: @interjay: Actually, you're right. Let me think about this some more.

Comment: Yeah, it should work now, +1. I don't think the exam question is very good because it requires you to either use floating point to count the digits, or use a loop (which is silly when the point is to use recursion).

Comment: @interjay: Agreed. Sadly, I think it's quite common, for some reason most "didactic" examples of recursion are not very good uses of recursion.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `return(rest * 10 + invert(div))`. You can't do the multiplication yourself. The factor depends on the number of times the function is recursed, thus you have to provide the carry as a second argument to your function (carry is initialized with 0)

Answer (score -1):

This is the simplest approach.

```
int sum=0;
int reverse(int n)
{
    if(n>0)
    {
        sum=(sum*10)+(n%10);
        reverse(n/10);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a global variable?